# How do I compare printed array index to see if they're a pair

Tags: c++, arrays, playing-cards

Draw 2 cards from the deck and check if they are a pair (having the same rank). Repeat this at least 1000 times and calculate the probability of drawing a pair from a deck of cards.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int counter;


string facevalue[] = { "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight","Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };


string suit [] = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs" };

string getcard() {
    string card;
    int cardvalue = rand() % 13;
    int cardsuit = rand() % 4;

    card += facevalue[cardvalue];
    card += " of ";
    card += suit[cardsuit];

    if(cardvalue = cardvalue){
        counter = counter + 1;
    }


    return card;
}

int main() {
    int numberofcards = 2;
    int times = 1000;


    for (int y =0; y < times; y++){

    cout<<" "<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofcards; i++) {
        cout << "You drew a " << getcard() << endl;

     }
     }

     cout<<"counter: "<<counter<<endl;




}
```

So here, cardvalue controls what gets printed out from the array. So if cardvalue is 1 then facevalue[cardvalue] will be facevalue[1], which will print out "Two."

So right now I am trying to determine how many times will cardvalue be the same when picking 2 cards randomly from the deck.

I did

```
    if(cardvalue = cardvalue){
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
```

The result I get is 926, meaning there are 926 times that the card value will be the same when drawing 2 cards out of a deck 1000 times. That doesn't seem right, would be much appreciated if anyone can correct my program or guide me through the process.

I tried    (cardvalue == cardvalue)
but I get counter : 2000 instead.

Comment: Do you expect `cardvalue == cardvalue` to be `false` sometimes? Please form a meaningful expression. What is even worse is that you think this can be done without remembering the picked cards...

Comment: @LogicStuff So if cardvalue == cardvalue is true then counter++, but if cardvalue == cardvalue is false then I don't want to add it to counter. Sorry for asking, but what options are there for me?

Comment: @mrtammy: we mean, adding extra variable `lastCardValue` might be useful.

Comment: Can you redraw the same card, or do you pick 2 different cards ? probability of pair is 4/52(-> 1/13) for the first case, 3/51 for the second case.

Comment: Initialize counter to 0 and do not compare cardvalue with itself, it is nonsense.

Comment: `if(cardvalue = cardvalue)` - are you sure?

Comment: You have two problems.  1.) You are not drawing two cards from a deck.  You are drawing 1 card from a deck two times.  It would be the equivalent of drawing a card and then replacing it before drawing the next card.  2.)  You have to store the previous card value somewhere to compare the new one against.  "if (cardvalue == cardvalue)"  will ALWAYS be true.  It is like comparing 15 to 15.

Comment: @Jarod42 Pick 2 different cards from a deck. I am not supposed to be putting the card back and then redrawing from the deck. Also what do you mean by adding an extra variable, where should I be putting it under.

Comment: When you do `cardvalue == cardvalue`, when do you expect that it is evaluated to `false`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I expect cardvalue == cardvalue to be false when they don't match, so say 2 == 2 would be true, while 4 == 2 would be false. What I want to do is for my program to record down how many true will there be when the program loops 1000 times.

Comment: How can you have the test `4 == 2` ? You can't have both `cardvalue == 4` and `cardvalue == 2` with the same variable. with `cardvalue1 == cardvalue2` it would have make sense.

Comment: @Jarod42 yup, got it now. I should have made 2 variables to store both card 1 and card 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work directly with index instead of string, you may have something like:

```
int color_of_card(int i)
{
    return i / 13;
}

int value_of_card(int i)
{
    return i % 13;
}

std::string card_as_string(int i)
{
    static const std::string facevalues[] = {
        "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
        "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"
    };
    static const std::string suits[] = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs" };

    return facevalues[value_of_card(i)] + " of " + suits[color_of_card(i)];
}

int getcard() {
    return rand() % 52;
}

int main() {
    const int times = 1000;

    int counter = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y != times; y++)
    {
        auto card1 = getcard();
        auto card2 = getcard();
        while (card1 == card2) { card2 = getcard(); } // Ensure cards differ.

        if (value_of_card(card1) == value_of_card(card2)) {
            ++counter;
        }
    }
    std::cout << counter << std::endl;  // 58 or 59 normally
    // Once you took a card, there are only 3 card on same value
    // and there is 51 remaining cards.
    std::cout << 3 / 51.f << std::endl; // 0.0588235
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/bEASYd)

Answer (score 0):

First remove your global counter variable, it is a bad practice.

Then you may try something like that :

```
int main() {
    int numberofcards = 2;
    int times = 1000;
    int counter = 0;

    std::map<string, int> cardMap;
    string currentCard;
    int maxNbSameCard;
    for (int y =0; y < times; y++){
       cardMap.clear();
       maxNbSameCard = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < numberofcards; i++) {
          currentCard = getcard();
          cardMap[currentCard]+=1;

          cout << "You drew a " << currentCard << endl;
          cout << "It is the " << cardMap[currentCard] << " time you get this card" << endl;
          if(maxNbSameCard < cardMap[currentCard]) maxNbSameCard = cardMap[currentCard];
         }
     if(maxNbSameCard > 1) ++counter;
     }

     cout<<"counter: "<<counter<<endl;
}
```

1. note that "=" is an affectation not a comparison.
2. it's not the job of getcard() to count pairs, it is only a card creator, it has no visibility about previously created cards.